# Strange Zend issue with action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I got a system written in Zend Framework and Bootstrap. It is working properly in a server but I need to put it in another server.

I got a section to articles but when I try to open some article in this new server it show the error:

> Message: Action "NameOfMyArticleTest" does not exist and was not trapped in __call(),

This is really weird because in the old server it works properly and the code is the same.

Comment: Do the Bootstrap and ZF versions match on both servers?

Comment: @MattK well i put all the files in this new server? how can i check it?

Comment: @MattK they are the same files of o old server and it is working properly in old server.

Comment: @MattK I thought it could be a php configuration but idk

Comment: There's a couple different ways but you could look in Zend/Version.php, it will be a constant near the top. For Bootstrap you could look at the comments in one of the files like bootstrap.css

Comment: @MattK, ok moment i will check it

Comment: @MattK, well the zend version is 1.11.12 but the bootstrap version i can't find in files is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a routing problem.

The __call() method is triggered if Zend isn't able to find any appropriate methods in the controller. 
Your routing is looking for a NameOfMyArticleTestAction method in the Articles (?) controller class.

olddomain.com/articles/name-of-article-test was routed to the correct method in the Articles class, just should see and check whether the domainname has any influence on this routing.

Good luck.

Oh, P.S.

You can check the bootstrap version in one of the .css files, the file starts with something like

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.2.0 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * etc.
 */
```